# showing progressDialog during loading a Webview (Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

My process for loading a webview takes a while and I would like to show a wait dialog for this.

In the past I did the following: (but with the new Android API I get the Error "A WebView method was called on thread"):

- showed the progressdialog:
  `progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");`
- then in a thread I loaded the webview and send a message to a handler which closed the progressDialog:

.

```
new Thread() {
     public void run() {
     String myHTML=generateHTML();  <-- long runner
     wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("ImagesPath, myHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
     CloseProgressHandler.sendMessage(mymessage);
       }
    }.start();
```

Now I had to recode it to prevent the error "A WebView method was called on thread" with Webview.post(new Runnable():

`progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");`

```
 wv.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     String myHTML=generateHTML();  <-- long runner
     wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("ImagesPath, myHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
     CloseProgressHandler.sendMessage(mymessage);
       }
    }.start();
```

After my recoding the ProgressDialog doesn't appear anymore. It will not show up before Webview.post is running.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong ? Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

use below method

```
    private void startWebView(String url) {
    //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    //When opening a url or click on link

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }); 

     // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    // Other webview options
    /*
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    */

    /*
     String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
     webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
     */

    //Load url in webview
    //webView.loadUrl(url);



   //Update1 Start
     wv.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
             String myHTML=generateHTML();
             wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("ImagesPath, myHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
             CloseProgressHandler.sendMessage(mymessage);
               }
            }.start();

    //Update1 End

}
```

call like this in your activity's onCreate() method

```
 //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    startWebView("https://www.google.com/");
```

**Update 2**

You can use this then

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
      public void run(){

       try{
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
        }catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
}, 5000);
```

progress will be canceled after 5 sec

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I guess thats the right way. But in practice I have trouble. What is ShowWebView in your case ? I get a syntax error.

Comment: I got it. ShowWebView is the activity itself. I am just testing this. Thanks.

Comment: replace ShowWebView.this with yourActivityName.this

Comment: It doesn't work. I mean I can see the dialog for a lilisecond, but after the page is loaded. 1. click on load 2. Page loads for some seconds 3. I can see the progress dialog for a milisecond.

Comment: Sorry forgot something to mention. I have to call the webview with wv.post(new Runnable() as described in the question, because otherwise I get other problems ( "A WebView method was called on thread")

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. I do not see a difference. The wv.post I was already doing, otherwise no webpage would be displayed. The page is displayed but the progressdialog flickers uponly very short after loading. How to show the progressDialog at start of loading the page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78711/discussion-between-qadir-hussain-and-mcfly-soft).

Comment: Yes once the page is loaded completely the progressDialog will be dismissed. if it loads in milisec then you will see the progressDialog for milisec

Comment: Sorry I missleaded the hole thing here. Your code is working fine, but my problem is different. My longconsuming task is not loading the webpage itself it is the generateHTML function in my sample. How to show a progress dialog for this when it is inside the wv.post ?

Comment: This is very huge and it takes time. Its not the question to optimize this :-) You can assume the task will take 5 seconds. Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. But of course the generateHTML does not take 5 secs every time. One time 10 secs another time 20 sec one other time 3 secs. We don't know. I should show the progress when generating the HTML and close it when finished. Is this possible with this solution ? the duration will also depend on the device processors.

Comment: in this case 1st solutions is good i think. anyways May be im not getting the question. This is all I can do :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1st solution doesn't do it. But anyway thanks a lot.